# Properly scale a vector to fit a raster layer

Tags: d3.js, gdal, shapefile, topojson

So I've created a clipped and reprojected raster image from a Natural Earth 2 data set. It is simple enough to set that as a base layer and project a vector layer on top of it. The problem I'm having is properly scaling the images so they align perfectly.

Please refer to this block for the example: http://bl.ocks.org/mkessy/8545864

Here is what I've done so far:
Use gdalwarp to reproject the raster to Albers Equal Area and clip to the bounding box of North Dakota, output the image to my desired resolution (960 x 500)
In D3 I use the exact same projection and overlay the vector onto the raster
Now how do I go about adjusting the scale so that it properly aligns the 2 layers? I'm thinking it may do with the resolution of the original raster, perhaps I've distorted it by resizing? I know how to automatically compute scale based off the bounding box but it still doesn't fit the raster layer. I've looked at several examples and cannot figure out how the author computed the scales: see [Costa Rica](http://bl.ocks.org/mjhoy/5301594) and the New York Times Border Graphic, 3/2/2013) (can't post link). In both cases the scale parameter passed to the d3.geo object is a magic integer as far as I can tell.

Comment: For both the original raster image and the reprojection you should have a scale that you could work out the final scale from, no?

Comment: So I'm using [this](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-raster-data/10m-natural-earth-2/) data set which is 1:10m. I guess I'm confused as how to reconcile the original raster scale, its reprojected scale, and then the scale of the d3 vector.  How would I go about calculating the d3 projection scale once the raster is created since it cannot be modified after it comes out of gdalwarp?

Comment: If you're not changing the scale when reprojecting, it should still be the original scale. Then you need to take into account the scale it's shown at (i.e. size of the map on screen and original scale) and that should give you the value you need to plug in to D3.