# How do we load a raster overlay on a D3.js vector map?

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, gis

We're building an interactive visualization of various formats of geospatial data.

We've loaded GeoJSON of country borders onto our map, as well as linestring and point data - all works well and is spatially accurate.

How do we accurately overlay a georeferenced raster image on top of our vector basemap?

We've found and looked at these resources, but they're either not perfectly relevant or too complex to pick out specifically what we need:

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/5342063

[Properly scale a vector to fit a raster layer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21373149/properly-scale-a-vector-to-fit-a-raster-layer)

Comment: Do you need to zoom and pan with the raster? Also, do you need to re-project the raster on the fly to match the desired visualization's projection?

Comment: @AndrewReid Ideally, yes, we'd like that option. That must add a fair bit of complexity though, no?